# Problem updating 11.10

Tags: 11.10, updates, internet-connection

When I try to update my OS to the newer version of Ubuntu, suddenly pops a window saying that some packages can't be downloaded because the internet connection is not working properly.
I'm pretty sure the connection is just fine, but I would like to know how to test it. 
And, if it's not that, how can I solve the updating problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may just be detecting certain software sources as unavailable.  If the sources mention jaunty, especially jaunty backports when you're on 11.10, you probably don't need them any more, and can certainly test the system with them turned off, since you could just turn them back on later.

Go to `Ubuntu > System > Administration > Software Sources` 
(or the equivalent on your system, maybe in synaptic or ubuntu software center)

And toggle off the repositories/archives mentioned in the error.

If you need them for some reason, feel free to toggle them back on after a successful update (I generally don't, though).

Comment: I can't find those archives. Nothing pops when I search for jaunty backports in synaptic (origins)

Answer (score 0):

launch the `apt-get update` and verify if you have a problem with the repository. After this repeat the updating.

;-)

Comment: And how do I know if I have a problem with the repository?? the message I get is this one
W:Imposible obtener http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-backports/restricted/source/Sources